# Error Message : libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key emailTxt

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am new at iOS programming, and I get an error message

`libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7f9230a05100> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key emailTxt.'`

I don't understand, I removed the emailTxt, and it still appears...

I deleted and add again in my storyboard, but I always get this error.

Comment: Your storyboard doesn't refer to your custom view controller subclass. It is using `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check all the objects in the storyboard connected to its IBOutlet, and try to check if there is some Outlet that are alone (with the cross), not connected.
Are you sure that you are touching the good storyboard, and you are not updating the bad one ?

(Essentially, the mistake I encounter with that kind of error message was that when I transferred the storyboards from one project to another, I forgot to update the names and actions of the UI components in the storyboard to match the new project. As a result, I encountered this error.)

Comment: Thank you very much, that exactly what I have done. I copied a storyboard to another, and I forgot to update the names and action.